# Prevent child from rerender when it updates parents state using parent method as prop in react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I have a parent component and two child components. so i want to update second component when some action is performed in first component. Say I have Component1 and Component2, and a ParentComponent, so when I change state of ParentComponent from Component1  it changes the state in Component2 but also rerenders component1. I dont want to rerender component1. Tried to use callback but didnot help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memo` to handle this scenario:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* only rerenders if props change */
});
```

Such component will only be re-rendered when there is a change in its own state or props.

Comment: I have tried that but it still rerenders child component1 because it finds the function to change the state of the parent as updated prop. can you tell what should i do to prevent that?